# Heroku - Erro executar seeder para popular BD

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku, adonisjs, seeders

Olá.

Recentemente realizei o deploy de uma aplicação no heroku (Node + Adonis + MySql + React) e estou enfrentando alguns probleminhas. Ela possui um usuário admin que é responsável por cadastrar outros usuários, então eu possuo alguns seeders para popular o banco com alguns dados e os usuários (admin e usuario comum). Para rodar os seeders no heroku eu utilzei o seguinte comando.

`heroku run -a allocate-ufc-back ENV_SILENT=true node ace seed --force`

Após utilizar esse comando ele gera o seguinte erro:

[image: Print do erro]

É como se não existisse a coluna, ou algo assim, pelo menos foi o que eu entendi. Eu não sei como faço para visualizar as tabelas do meu banco no heroku por isso não da pra saber se está conectando corretamente. Se alguém pudesse me ajudar a identificar qual o problema ou dizer como rodar o seeders corretamente ficaria muito grata. Detalhe: as migrations foram executadas normalmente.

Answer (score 1):

Você está passando pelo mesmo problema que essa situação [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659691/error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails). O erro está em como está usando a relação de chave estrangeira/index de suas tabelas no banco de dados.

> Um relacionamento de chave estrangeira envolve uma tabela pai que contém os valores iniciais da coluna e uma tabela filho com valores de coluna que fazem referência aos valores da coluna pai. Uma restrição de chave estrangeira é definida na tabela filho.